# Understanding Fortran pointers

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, intel-fortran

In Fortran one can allocate memory to a pointer, or one cannot:

```
real(kind=jp), target :: bt(100,100)
real(kind=jp), pointer :: pt(:,:)
```

But then you can allocate memory to the pointer `pt`:

```
allocate(pt(100,100))
```

My question is: what are the pros and cons? For all I can see, allocating memory to the pointer defeats the purpose of a pointer and uses up more memory. Granted, my knowledge of pointers is limited so if some could explain to me what going on here, I would grateful.

I'm using a model with mixed FORTRAN 77 and Fortran 90 code, plus, I'm compiling the code using Intel compilers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Vladimir F said in a comment to another answer, there may well be some confusion as to what the example code is doing.  Although not a wide answer all about pointers (which is already partly covered), I'll comment briefly.

```
real(kind=jp), target :: bt(100,100)
real(kind=jp), pointer :: pt(:,:)
```

The pointer `pt` is not at this point pointing to anything: it has undefined association status.  That you have the two objects declared together, one with the `target` attribute and one with the `pointer` attribute, doesn't signify something.

To associate `pt` with the target `bt`, pointer assignment is required:

```
pt => bt
```

In this way, one can go ahead and do things to `bt` through the pointer `pt` without any extra memory allocation (there will be some overhead associated with the pointer variable, but let's ignore that).

Yes, one also could do pointer allocation as in the question

```
allocate(pt(100,100))
```

but this newly minted lump of memory has nothing to do with `bt`.

As [Alexander Vogt said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28929305/) in modern times there are reduced reasons to want to do that sort of thing (using allocatable arrays instead is a good thing to consider).

In summary, for "what are the pros and cons?": pointer assignment and allocation do totally different things.  Choose whichever is appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Allocatable pointers as you use them were widely in use before dummy arguments could be `allocatable` (Fortran 2003). This way you could pass an array and allocate it in another routine, which is immensely helpful for input routines where you don't know the input size before-hand.

Allocated pointers behave very similarly to the usual counterparts, but are not automatically deallocated. Some say that using pointers this way is detrimental on performance, but I have never experienced this myself (probably compiler specific). One issue with pointers, though, is possible aliasing when used as dummy arguments.

Nowadays, I would not use pointers when I could use an `allocatable` array instead. This has many benefits, key among them is the automatic deallocation and better readability of the code. (If you like, you can also use automatic allocation of the LHS, but I usually turn that off).

For OOP pointers are essential and I use them a lot for e.g. linked lists, trees, etc. If you have nested derived types, it is also quite elegant to use pointers to reduce de-referencing.

Comment: I have a different concern, the OP does not mention `allocatable` at all. I am not sure if he correctly understands what the three lines of code in is question do.

Comment: I'm not a pro programmer, but in my line of work, I do a lot of programming tasks that often require that I choose the optimal way to solve a problem and not just do it in a brutal way. Unfortunately, I come across a lot of old code and must try and understand what going. So, yes, I didn't fully understand pointers in Fortran. My first encounter with pointers was in C.My main concern was memory consumption. Now I understand a bit better. In my current task, we use derived types to pass around lots of data in the form of pointers with allocated memory. Thanks guys :-)